# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/Cordova350.app/Cordova350

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, telerik, application-loader, icenium

I have written and exported a Cordova 3.5.0 PhoneGap Application using the Telerik Platform. The app is using jQuery Mobile and an InAppPurchasing plugin.
The only other plugins used are Cordova Splashscreen and Cordova Statusbar.

I can run the app no problem when i install it via iTunes on to my iPad. However, when I submit the app via Application Loader, I get the following errors:

[image: _canShowMIMEType:, ignore, uiWebView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionLister, webView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener]

I was tempted to go in and edit/look for the lines that reference these 'non-public selectors' myself but the Cordova350 file is a unix executable file that when opened looks like bytes of hex codes.

I cant seem to find anything from googling around about anyone experiencing a similar issue. Is this just a setting somewhere I have forgotten to untick? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check to make sure you aren't using Telerik AppFeedback or Mobile Testing - there may be incompatibilities with submitting apps that are meant for testing purposes to Apple.

Comment: do you mean things like the 'live sync' feature?

Comment: LiveSync shouldn't matter (although it should probably be turned off for a production-ready build).